# Server 2003 DNS Issues

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-sbs-2003

We are having a certain issue at a client where the internet will stop working and when I do a ping test to a website, it replies Pinging www.google.com (10.0.0.1) and then the pings fail.  However, when I restart the DNS server service on the server (it's a Server 2003 SBS), it starts working and the ping test replies Pinging www.google.com (74.125.224116) and the pings are all successful.  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

An IP like that is probably being generated by a router when the Internet goes down.

The thinking being: If the Internet is down, the router will make every page they try to go to redirect to a page saying "The Internet is down" or possibly "You must log in/agree to our terms of service before you access the Internet", and some routers have a proxy that makes all DNS queries have an answer like 10.0.0.1, so users can see the message.